# Show the last record if meets certain conditions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables for example USER and AUDIT, where the join is `user.id = audit.record`:

USER:

```
 ID,  USER,  NAME,  LAST_NAME

 205, USER1, PEDRO, PEREZ

 206, USER2, JUAN,  PEREZ
```

AUDIT:

```
 ID, ACTION, RECORD, FIELD,     DATE

 1, MODIFY,  205,    LAST_NAME, 08/11/12

 2, MODIFY,  205,    NAME,      25/09/12

 3, MODIFY,  206,    NAME,      08/11/12
```

I need a query where the result shows all the users that his last registry entry have a modification in its name. In the example the result would be just `USER2`

I'm using Oracle 8, can i use a simple query or do i need to create a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for the format Nicholas Krasnov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution... `MAX (FIELD_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY OPERATION_DT)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do it:

```
select id from user u,
               audit a
 where  u.id=a.record
 and a.action='MODIFY'
 and a.field='NAME'
 and a.id = (select max(id) 
             from audit a2
             where a2.record=u.id)
```

Comment: Here is how do i solve it...

MAX (FIELD_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY OPERATION_DT)